# determine if particular div has any child existed inside dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I determine if some particular div has any child existed inside dom

```
<div class="profile-feed row">
   <div class="col-sm-6"> </div> // does this particular div has any child?
...
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var count = $(".col-sm-6").children().length;
```

If you have multiple elements with this class, this method will return number of all children's from all elements with this id. To be more specific, i suggest to use id selector or add the parent selector. Please see this example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9qa1qm9s/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($( ".col-sm-6" ).children().length>0){
    alert('childern found')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of child elements

```
var len = $(".col-sm-6").children().length;
if(len > 0)
   alert('Child exist');
else
   alert('Child does not exist');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery's `children()`

```
var kids = $('.col-sm-6').children();
if(kids.length > 0) {
    alert('has children')
}
```

further information here: [jQuery Children](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1zIujNK6TPJKjbGcaDjz?p=preview

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    if($('.col-sm-6').children().length > 0) $('.status').text('div has child');
    else $('.status').text('no child');
  });

</script>
```

Just use jQuery children -> returns array and then get length :)

Answer (score 0):

**Using native JS**

```
var profile = document.querySelectorAll('.profile-feed .col-sm-6');
var childs = profile[0].querySelectorAll('*');
```